# Isolate styling of injected content from page CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe

I have a JavaScript plugin that injects some HTML & CSS code into webpages. Some of the injected code is from a 3rd party package which I have limited ability to modify.

Given that the styling on the host page is unpredictable (since I cannot predict which sites the user will run the plugin on), how can I design the injected code (HTML + CSS) to be impervious to the external styling and only use the styling included by the plugin.

For instance, if the host page has a style for DIV elements, I would like to ensure this styling is not applied to any of the DIVs in the injected code

Comment: You can inspect the webpage and look for a `class` being used on elements to style a theme... You could use that same `class` name on your elements so the same style properties will be applied. Without a working example it is impossible to give you a solid solution. If you can give an example of the `javascript` you are using and a domain name/URL to a page that you are working with might help myself and other offer you something more than suggestions. [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, there are two approaches:

1. Using dynamic css class. You can use some bundle tools, like grunt, gulp, .. to generate the dynamic css class when building the release for production.

On development mode:

```
<div class="box"></div>
css:
box{
  .red{}
}
```

On production mode:

```
<div class="d2fdcdf_dfdafdaf"></div>
css:
.d2fdcdf_dfdafdaf{
  .red{}
}
```

2. Using inline style or important! directive

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to maintain a clear CSS rule naming convention that would be impervious to naming collisions -- much the same way CSS frameworks like Bootstrap, Grid or Foundation do.

There are some nice models you can use to outline a convention that works best for your brain. For example, the Block Element Modifier model (BEM):

```
.block {}
.block__element {}
.block--modifier {}
.block__element--modifier {}
```

For example

```
.stick-man {}

.stick-man__head {}
.stick-man__head--small {}
.stick-man__head--big {}

.stick-man__arms {}
.stick-man__feet {}

.stick-man--blue {}
.stick-man--red {}
```

Other ideas surrounding this are:

- SMACSS—Scalable and Modular Architecture for CSS (SMACSS)
- Object Oriented CSS (OOCSS)
- Atomic CSS (ACSS)